# checksum in address

Tags: address, private-key, public-key

I want to create a address bitcoin.

I have a payload with version like this:

```
0050d512c984b1656ef47c145c8fd5d5262d3904b1
```

where `00` in my version prefix, and `50d512c984b1656ef47c145c8fd5d5262d3904b1` is my payload.

Now I Want to add checksum, with sha256 twice, the result is

```
4550e2041dd936f17fd8a0d60f17c69faea8ef0e7d3ee82383153d93c2e837a8
```

where the first 4 bytes is checksum **4550e204**

Now I can convert to base58

```
0050d512c984b1656ef47c145c8fd5d5262d3904b1**4550e204**
```

And I Get the right address.

I can read that

> These four bytes serve as the error-checking code, or checksum. The
>   checksum is concatenated (appended) to the end.

How Can I check if my checksum (**4550e204**) is correct before base58 ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. You have described the derivation for the checksum given version&payload. Given a base58 address, you decode the address for the version+payload+checksum. From that you can verify the version+payload. What other scenario do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to check is to use a tool like https://github.com/keis/base58 that implements base58check (`-c`) encoding and decoding (`-d`) with checksum verification to try to decode the final address:

```
$ printf "0050d512c984b1656ef47c145c8fd5d5262d3904b14550e204" | xxd -r -p | base58
18NQJwokxLGA7KsHJdQWh6ANB46K6nP7Hm
$ printf "18NQJwokxLGA7KsHJdQWh6ANB46K6nP7Hm" | base58 -c -d | xxd -p
0050d512c984b1656ef47c145c8fd5d5262d3904b1
```

Now, change the checksum and see if it is able to decode:

```
$ printf "0050d512c984b1656ef47c145c8fd5d5262d3904b14550e203" | xxd -r -p | base58
18NQJwokxLGA7KsHJdQWh6ANB46K6nP7Hk
Jordans-MacBook-Pro:~ Jbaczuk$ printf "18NQJwokxLGA7KsHJdQWh6ANB46K6nP7Hk" | base58 -c -d | xxd -p
Invalid checksum
```

Comment: thanks, for do checksum the operation is  decode base58 -and reply  `printf 0050d512c984b1656ef47c145c8fd5d5262d3904b1 |xxd -r -p | sha256sum -b | xxd -r -p | sha256sum -b | head -c 8`and Check the output with last 4 bytes ?

Comment: Yes, the first four bytes of the HASH256 is the checksum, which is appended to the end of the value to encode.